# what would be a good csv data analysis tool/framework

Tags: csv, data-analysis

is there good tool to analyse some csv-formatted data files. is there any easy to use open source thing to display data from csv-files? (please don't mention excel...). most important is an easy file import (or maybe folder read-out) mechanism.

Comment: as I said, please don't mention excel (and its clones)...

Comment: Why using Excel or any basic speadsheet application is a bad idea: https://theonemanitdepartment.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/the-absolute-minimum-everyone-working-with-data-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-file-types-encoding-delimiters-and-data-types-no-excuses/

Comment: you can use pandas which has many built in functions to extract specific data from your csv which needs to be analyzed and you machine learning algorithms using python libraries like random forest or decision tress to analyze your data .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found D3 to be the best solution: http://d3js.org/

Comment: Looks great.+1. There is some  amount of learning curve though it seems.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent tool is [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). It accepts data in csv as well as arff format. It is free and open source, can be used to visualize as well as to run inbuilt machine learning algorithms to gain more insights into the data.
The best thing is that it is extremely light weight and easy to use, you don't need anything except support for `java`.

Get it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/). Once started, it looks like : 
[image: !]

Now go to Explorer, open file and you are done!

Comment: hey, thnx! I need to analyse more than one files.

Comment: @headkit Hmm. We used this for out data mining labs and it worked well. Though i am not very sure what you mean by more than 1 files, but i think you should give it a try. Best of luck anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

IBM's [Many Eyes](http://www-958.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/manyeyes/) project is a free web-based collaborative tool that has lots of charts available.

Better, but expensive, are [Spotfire](http://spotfire.tibco.com/) and [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/). Both are amazing commercial applications for this, and Spotfire especially is incredibly easy to use to explore lots of visualizations side-by-side. Both have a desktop version and an online web player ([Spotfire demo gallery](http://spotfire.tibco.com/demo/default.aspx), [Tableau demo gallery](http://www.tableausoftware.com/learn/gallery)). They are both highly scalable, into the millions of rows. Both have free trials.

Comment: Many Eyes looks very interesting, but seems to a) run on the IBM servers and b) doesn't seem to have for my eyes only data presentations. but thanx a lot!